# JQuery: change content of <div> every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I've set up a radio broadcast server using xml and xslt.
I display the current song playing, but of course, that changed every minute, so I'd like that the `<div>` refreshes every second to make sure the displayed data is up-to-date.

I've written a JQuery function, but that does not work.
Also, i've written following test function to test if jquery works, and it doesn't.

Could it be that jquery does not work in an XST page??

Test function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
          alert("test");
            });
        });
```

The alert is not displayed when I click on a hyperlink...

This is my current code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match = "/icestats" >
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".newscontent").load("status.xsl");
        }, 1000);
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    window.onload = startTime;
    function startTime()
    {
    var date = new Date();
    var uur = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();

    if(min == 0 || min == 1 || min == 2 || min == 3 || min ==4 || min == 5 || min == 6 || min == 7 || min == 8 || min == 9)
    {
    min = "0" + min;
    }
    if(sec == 0 || sec == 1 || sec == 2 || sec == 3 || sec ==4 || sec == 5 || sec == 6 || sec == 7 || sec == 8 || sec == 9)
    {
    sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    var movingtime = uur + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = movingtime;
    setTimeout('startTime()',500);
    }
  </script>

  <title>Muziekserver</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<h2>Overzicht</h2>
<br />
<!--index header menu -->
<div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop">
<img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#656565">
        <a class="nav" href="admin/">Administratie</a>
        <a class="nav" href="status.xsl">Overzicht van muziek</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="roundbottom">
<img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<!--end index header menu -->
<!--mount point stats-->
<xsl:for-each select="source">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="listeners">
<div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop">
<img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
<div class="newscontent">
    <div class="streamheader">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <colgroup align="left" />
            <colgroup align="right" width="300" />
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Naam:  <xsl:value-of select="@mount" /></h3></td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="authenticator">
                        <td align="right"><a class="auth" href="/auth.xsl">Login</a></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td align="right"> Speel af als <a href="{@mount}.m3u">M3U</a> of als <a href="{@mount}.xspf">XSPF</a></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </tr></table>
    </div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="4" id="info">
<xsl:if test="server_name">
<tr><td>Naam</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="server_name" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="server_description">
<tr><td>Beschrijving</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="server_description" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="genre">
<tr><td>Genre</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="genre" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="bitrate">
<tr><td>Bitrate</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="bitrate" /> kbps</td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="quality">
<tr><td>Quality:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="quality" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="video_quality">
<tr><td>Video Quality:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="video_quality" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="frame_size">
<tr><td>Framesize:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="frame_size" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="frame_rate">
<tr><td>Framerate:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="frame_rate" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="server_url">
<tr><td>URL</td><td class="streamdata"> <a target="_blank" href="{server_url}"><xsl:value-of select="server_url" /></a></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<tr><td>Nu bezig</td><td class="streamdataArtist"> 
<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:value-of select="artist" /> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="roundbottom">
<img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<h3><xsl:value-of select="@mount" /> - Not Connected</h3>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>nbsp;


</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a reference to the jQuery library in the `<head>` of the document.

Example:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
...
</head>
```

While troubleshooting Javascript issues, it may be useful to install Firebug (for Firefox) or use the Developer Tools for Chrome. Each contains a console that will report Javascript errors. In your case, you will see an error like:

```
'$ is not defined'
```

which means that jQuery is not working.

**UPDATE**

In response to your updated code, please note that the following is incorrect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".newscontent").load("status.xsl");
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".newscontent").load("status.xsl");
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

The first `<script>` element gets its body from the URL in the `src` attribute. A second `<script>` element must be created the Javascript specific to your page.

Comment: @Laurent De Wilde: Can you report the error output from the console, as described above?

Comment: Current code: ----------
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
     $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                    $(".newscontent").load("status.xsl");
                    }, 1000);
            });
    </script>

Comment: Console output is empty, when I toggle a breakpoint, Firebug does not jump into it... But $ active=0 and jquery active=0 as well...

Comment: Can you update your post with the current state of your code, including the addition of the jQuery library reference and the part that contains the `alert()`?

Comment: Also very strange that when i toggle a breakpoint at "function startTime", firebug goes into the code, but when toggling a breakpoint at JQuery, it does not debug...

Comment: Okay, de div class updated every second, that worked, thanks!

Comment: BUT now I have another problem: for each data stored in the xml tag, it duplicates the whole page.
So i.e. <artist></artist> has 8 values and the whole page is displayed 8 times under each other.
How comes?

Comment: @Laurent De Wilde: To avoid a continuation of the extended discussion, I recommend that you open a new question to address that issue. You may wish to post an example snippet of your XML along with the code that creates the output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to include the jQuery library.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval() is what you need.

Also, think about using the jQuery ready method instead of onLoad as well as put a reference to the jQuery tag about the script tag you have the code in.

Comment: What do you mean by "put a reference to the jQuery tag about the script tag you have the code in."?